# solution for touch screen select option(html Select tag)

Tags: android, html, ios, select, touch

I need help on solution for touch screen select option(html Select tag).

select option like select country and state are very hard to select in big touch screen. like mobile android(have image attached) and IOS using wrapper to expand select option, I need similar solution which I can use in my application.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of example of POS made in Java for touch screen design and its open source
check it out http://www.openbravo.com/product/pos/